# How to write HTML in Wordpress post

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress Post, (for teaching) I wanted to show this:

`<h1> This is my first h1 heading</h1>`

I tried using `<pre></pre>, <code></code>, <raw></raw>` tags yet Wordpress interprets them and puts it in h1 style.

Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't forget to upvote any answers that you find useful and accept the one that answers the question for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&lt;` instead of `<`.

This *represents* the angle bracket character, without *being* and angle bracket character, so WordPress will display it as such, instead of interpreting it as an HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

In the top corner of the editor there are tabs "visual" and "text".

Make sure your on visual

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your CSS in Appearance->Editor and look for 'pre'. You can style it as you'd like and then use that. Otherwise change your font size for H1's within the same stylesheet.

**As long as you are within the content in the tab labeled "Text"** you can write HTML.
It just depends on how these HTML tags are styled after that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're saving your HTML on the database.

All you need to do is store your data in a variable and then echo using [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php). For example, if you're inserting your HTML inside the content, do something like this:

```
<? 
   $content = get_the_content();
   echo html_entity_decode($content);
?>
```